# Mysterious error deploying sinatra app to heroku: bundler: failed to load command: rackup

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rack

I noticed that heroku is producing a mysterious error when I deploy my sinatra app. It works fine locally, and in fact, it runs fine on heroku as well--but this error appears in the heroku logs every time I deploy (and only upon deploy):

```
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579045+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rackup)
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579176+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: missing run or map statement
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579178+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:146:in `to_app'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579179+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config.ru:5:in `<main>'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579180+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579180+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579181+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579182+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579183+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579184+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579184+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579185+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579186+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.5/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579187+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.579215+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<top (required)>'
2017-04-26T08:52:25.724981+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-04-26T08:52:26.928566+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 56963`
2017-04-26T08:52:29.278571+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-26 08:52:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2017-04-26T08:52:29.278590+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-26 08:52:29] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux]
2017-04-26T08:52:29.278909+00:00 app[web.1]: == Sinatra (v1.4.8) has taken the stage on 56963 for production with backup from WEBrick
2017-04-26T08:52:29.279274+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-26 08:52:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=56963
2017-04-26T08:52:29.825875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Other posts suggest that this may be due to an error in `config.ru`. Mine simply contains:

```
require './lib/app'
SinatraApp.run!
```

Here's my `Procfile`:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
```

The [heroku deploy log is here](https://gist.github.com/lrettig/82e0f81b30304ed3fffe40edd078a82d), in case it's helpful. As I said, the app appears to be working fine (you can see it launch successfully at the end of the above transcript), but I can't understand what's causing this error on every deploy.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you provided the right `config.ru`? The traceback suggests that it has at least 5 lines: `/app/config.ru:5:in <main>`, and the source you included only has two lines.

Comment: Good point. I noticed this as well. There's only one `config.ru` in my project (I double checked). Is heroku deploying some sort of default `config.ru`? I can't find any evidence of this in the heroku docs, and when I connect to my dyno and examine the file, it's unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing [Rack’s `run` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Builder#run-instance_method) with [Sinatra’s `run!` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Base.run!).

When using `rackup`, Rack expects your `config.ru` to specify which app you want to run. You do this using the `run` (or `map`) methods. Your `config.ru` doesn’t have either of these, so when `rackup` runs it report the error you are seeing: `missing run or map statement`.

Sinatra has its own `run!` method. When you call this Sinatra will start a web server and serve your app. This server will respect the various Sinatra settings (e.g. `set :server, 'puma'` etc.). `rackup` doesn’t use thise settings. (I suspect you have a line something like `set :port, ENV['PORT']` in your app).

Your `config.ru` should look something like this, which should stop the error:

```
require './lib/app'
run SinatraApp
```

What’s happening is that when you start `rackup` it will parse your `config.ru` to configure the app to run. During this, since this file is plain Ruby, you start the built-in Sinatra server. This stops rackup from finishing, and leaves the built-in server running.

When you later stop the server you are only stopping this builtin server. Rack will continue to read `config.ru`, expecting to find an app to run so that it too can start a server. When it doesn’t find anything in raises an error.

In your case, what I think is happening is the error is being raised from the *previous* running server when you deploy a new version

Comment: Thanks. [This](https://gist.github.com/lrettig/6c74f79217e02dd012cdb743f1a59c56) is what I see in the log now when shutting down/restarting, after making the change you suggested. Is this what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: @LaneRettig yep, I think so. Those exceptions are Webrick responding to the SIGTERM that Heroku sends. If you [switch to e.g. Puma](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server) you shouldn’t see those.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as correct (thanks!) but I'm still a bit weirded out by all of the apparently innocuous error messages in the logs!